# Kubernetes, how to expose home cluster ip over the internet

Tags: kubernetes

I just got started with kubernetes since I'mm running a lot of services on my home server and I’ve thought would be a good idea to have everything in one place.This is what I intend doing:

- set up the ingress rules in a fashion so each service has its own endpoint
- configure the ingress controller so it points to the main pod (gateway) or I don't know. Excuse me if I'm wrong, yet picking on the terminology
- I want to hook that pod to my domain, problem being that this is a home hosted cluster, how could I possibly achieve that?

My end goal being to access the gateway outside my home network.

Could you please advise me on how to connect the pod to the domain please? I couldn't find anything over the internet that I could understand.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what do you mean by gateway pod, I'm going to assume its the lack of understanding so:

What you need is to set up an ingress controller (nginx ingress controller works like a charm), which then will let you create ingress objects.

After you create the ingress object and you can  make requests to localhost:80/your_service, you could use ngrok (https://ngrok.com/docs) to expose your port to the internet.